# Обработка файлов разных форматов C#

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем привет.
Есть класс, который занимается обработкой файлов разного формата (Html, Text, JSON …). Предполагается, что будут добавляться новые форматы файлов. Напишите реализацию, позволяющую расширять форматы обрабатываемых файлов. Детали обработки конкретного содержимого файла неважны.

```
public class FileProcessor
   { 
       public void ProcessFile(string fileName)
       {
            
       }  

   }
```

Я думаю нужно использовать шаблон стратегия, тип будет интерфейс IReader с методом readFile(string fileName), но опять же вопрос что он должен возвращять string для всех файлов ? И далее для обработки получается также использовать стратегию, тип на каждый файл своя обработка или считал в string и алгоритм общий для всех ? Или вообще по-другому. Интерфейс IFileProcess? и в нем считывает из своего формата и что то делает ?

Comment: Вам стоит сначала написать код для одного, потом для второго, потом для третьего и оценить, насколько легко или сложно вам было добавить второй и третий.

Comment: Без описания того, что за обработка, такое спрашивать совершенно бессмысленно.

Comment: Я отсановился на таком решении, здесь больше академический подход. Ну вот и сделаем как просят))) А что, добавлять новое легко ? Легко ! Проверка на формат есть )

Comment: Удалось разобраться? Если да, то можно отметить наиболее полезный ответ принятым.

Answer (score 0):

Оцените такое решение, думаю имеет место быть. Использовал шаблонный метод и стратегию

```
abstract class AbstractFileProcessor
{
    public void ProcessFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName) && Path.GetExtension(fileName).Contains(GetFormat()))
            StartWork(fileName);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("incorrect file format or file not exist");
    }

    protected abstract string GetFormat();
    protected abstract void StartWork(string fileName);
}

class FileProcessor
{
    public AbstractFileProcessor fileProcessor;

    public FileProcessor(AbstractFileProcessor fileProcessor) => this.fileProcessor = fileProcessor;

    public void ProcessFile(string fileName)
    {
        fileProcessor.ProcessFile(fileName);
    }
}

    protected abstract string GetFormat();
    protected abstract void StartWork(string fileName);
}

class HtmlProcess : AbstractFileProcessor
{
    protected override string GetFormat() => ".html";

    protected override void StartWork(string fileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process with html file");
    }
}

class JsonProcess : AbstractFileProcessor
{
    protected override string GetFormat() => ".json";

    protected override void StartWork(string fileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process with json file");
    }
}

class TextProcess : AbstractFileProcessor
{
    protected override string GetFormat() => ".txt";

    protected override void StartWork(string fileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process with txt file");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileProcessor fp = new FileProcessor(new HtmlProcess());
        fp.ProcessFile(@"C:\Users\danil\source\repos\FileWorker\FileWorker\hello.html");

        fp.fileProcessor = new TextProcess();
        fp.ProcessFile(@"C:\Users\danil\source\repos\FileWorker\FileWorker\hello.txt");

        fp.fileProcessor = new JsonProcess();
        fp.ProcessFile(@"C:\Users\danil\source\repos\FileWorker\FileWorker\hello.json");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Шаблонный метод, чтобы проверять вообще существует ли файл и его формат подходит для обработки данным классом

Comment: `void StartWork` - а данные то куда деваются? хранятся в классе? как к ним доступ получить? или что с ними происходит. Вот вы сделали API, а как ей пользоваться непонятно. Что на выходе?

Comment: А вопрос уже обработки хранения пересылки в этой задаче не важны, говорю она академическая. По условию задача, детали обработки конкретного содержимого файла неважны, поэтому прошу оценить моё решение.

Comment: Ваше решение не имеет осмысленности в коде, и не понятно, как это использовать. Приведите рабочий пример хотя-бы одного из обработчиков. Без прототипа нет смысла делать API. Вам стоит проверить, можно ли этим пользоваться, хотя-бы на примере одного конкретного файла. Почему я советую это сделать - потому что моя оценка этого кода "неуд", и предлагаю вам доказать обратное, так как я могу ошибаться и просто не понять задумку.

Comment: @aepot почему непонятно как использовать? сама идея понятна исходя из кода, а вот как можно привести "рабочий пример хотя бы одного из обработчиков" учитывая что речь идет о некой абстрактной операции обработки данных мне лично непонятно

Comment: @ArtemCherevan когда вы пишете код, вы его для чего-то пишете, верно? Так вот, здесь метод, выполняющий операцию, принимает имя файла и ничего не возвращает. Как забрать результат его работы? Если это коллбэк, надо где-то описать передачу делегата. Если это асинхронная операция, метод должен возвращать `Task<T>`. Если данные кладутся во внутренее хранилище, должно быть публичное свойство или метод для получения данных. Ничего этого нет, следовательно реализация либо ошибочная, либо неполноценная, пользоваться на деле этим никак не получится.